# admob test banner not showing in application

Tags: java, android

I am using AdMob test banner in my application everything works fine application opens but adds don't show

i have checked everything  `Manifest`, `bulid.gradle` etc everything is ok i don't know what is  going wrong

i'am using latest play-ads library

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private AdView mAdView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

}
}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
</application>
```

Red Lines in Logacat

```
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
```

`E/GooglePlayServicesUtil:` The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
W/DynamiteLoaderImpl: Failed to retrieve remote feature version

Comment: Can you share your xml file for ad please

Comment: <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="278dp"
        android:layout_height="168dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
       </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

Comment: Please try the answer.